# Android polygon overlay ontap

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

OK, I have used Google and found nothing to solve my problem, I have multiple polygons on a `MapView` and everything displays on the map correctly. What I am trying to do is add an `onTap` to display information about the polygon when one is tapped but I cannot get it to recognize the tap on the polygons. Below is what I currently have. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong in the `onTap` section?

```
public class Polygon extends Overlay {
ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints;
static ArrayList<String> custCount;
static ArrayList<String> hexCode;
static ArrayList<String> custMin;
static ArrayList<String> custMax;
static String tester;
Point firstPoint;
static List<HashMap<String, String>> colorRanges;

private Path path;

public Polygon(ArrayList<GeoPoint> points){
    geoPoints = points;
}
public class setColorRanges{



public setColorRanges(List<HashMap<String, String>> colorData) {

     colorRanges = colorData;
  }

}

public class  CustCount{
    public CustCount(ArrayList<String> str) {
        custCount = str;
    }
 }

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){


    //Set the color and style
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();

    //Create path and add points

    int origin = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < geoPoints.size()/5;i++){
        path = new Path();
        firstPoint = new Point();

        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoints.get(origin), firstPoint);
        path.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);

        for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
            Point nextPoint = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoints.get(origin+j), nextPoint);
            path.lineTo(nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);

        }
        //loop thru array of color ranges
        int curCustCount = Integer.valueOf(custCount.get(i));
        String curColor = "";
        for(int z=0; z<colorRanges.size(); z++) {
            int custmin = Integer.valueOf( colorRanges.get(z).get("custmin") );
            int custmax = Integer.valueOf( colorRanges.get(z).get("custmax") );

            if( curCustCount >= custmin && curCustCount <= custmax) {
                curColor = colorRanges.get(z).get("hexcode");
                break;
            }
        }

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(curColor));
        paint.setAlpha(70);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint1.setColor(Color.parseColor(curColor));
        paint1.setAlpha(100);
        paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        path.lineTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
        path.setLastPoint(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint1);

        origin += 5;
    }

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView) {

    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
    Region region = new Region();
    region.setPath(path, new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));

    Point point = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoint, point);

    if (region.contains(point.x, point.y)) {
        Log.d("onTap", point.x+" "+point.y);
    }

    return super.onTap(geoPoint, mapView);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing your `path` variable in `onDraw()`, You have --

```
path = new Path();
```

When you get to `onTap()` only the last path you drew is going to be saved as part of `path`.  So you will only register clicks on the last polygon.  If you are going to need all the paths later, you should save them in a `List` or other collection and iterate over them in `onTap()`.

Alternatively, you could render the polygons to a single `Path`, and only draw it and test once.  The problem there is you will not know which of the polygons was clicked on, just that one of them was.